# JasperReports Server 6.1.1 LDAP SSO

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, jasperserver

I tried [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-server-601-authentication-ntlm) tutorial, to get SSO working with *JasperReports Server (JRS)* 6.1.1 but I get the following Error in the *JRS* log:

```
2017-01-10 15:04:11,174 ERROR ContextLoader,localhost-startStop-1:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChainProxy' defined in ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security-web.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/multipleTenancy/DefaultMultiTenancyConfiguration
```

I don't know exactly what multi tenancy means, something like I could use several domains?

And the *JRS* won't start anymore, what did I wrong?

Comment: Try to find all jars with this (*DefaultMultiTenancyConfiguration*) class

Comment: But where, and where to put them if I found some?

Comment: Maybe you have duplicated jars at classpath (lib folder)

Comment: It's a completely new installation of *JRS* I tested it before and it works well. I jast added the Waffel files.

Comment: @AlexK If it's possible that we have to use the PRO version of JasperServer?